# Get file extention using only file name in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am creating a discord bot (irrelevent) that sends images into the chat. The user can type out the name of the image without needing to type the file extention. The problem is that the bot doesn't know what the file extention is so it will crash if the picture is a .jpg and the program was expecting a .png. Is there a way to make the program not require a file extention to open the file?

```
let image = imageName;
message.channel.send({ files: [`media/stickers/${imageName}.png`] });
```

Comment: how will it open the file if it doesn't know the full file name? the "extension" is part of the filename

Comment: @Bravo that's my question. I need it to open even if it doesn't know the extension.

Comment: do these files exist on your server? you can use `fs` functions to read the folder (readdir) then find the file whose name matches the given filename part - then you'll have the extension part

Comment: @Bravo I've never heard of that before, but that sounds like what I need. Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you use the "promise" version of `fs` you can find it by `const file = (await readdir(folder)).find(f => f.split('.').slice(0,-1).join('.') === target);` where `folder` is the folder the file is in, and `target` is the filename without the the extension

Comment: Added an answer using `readdir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the extension of the filename is required. You know `file.mp4` and `file.mp3` is entirely different.

However, you can use a try-except and a for loop to get the correct file!

I would suggest:

```
let image = imageName;
let extensions = [".png", ".jpg", "gif"] // All the extensions you can think of 
const pass = () => {}
for (const extension of extensions) {
  try {
     message.channel.send({ files: [`media/stickers/${imageName}${extension}`] }); // successfully get file and send
     break
  } catch(error) {
     pass() // do nothing, and go back to the loop and test other extension
  }
}
```

I haven't tried that before, and I am a Python programmer. But I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Using `fs` - specifically the Promise version of fs, makes this quite simple

```
import { readdir } from 'fs/promises';


const getFullname = async (path, target)  => 
    (await readdir(path))
    .find(file => 
        file === target || file.split('.').slice(0,-1).join('.') === target
    );
try {
    const actualName = await getExtension('media/stickers', imageName);
    if (!actualName) {
        throw `File ${imageName} not found`;
    }
    message.channel.send({ files: [`media/stickers/${actualName}`] });
} catch(error) {
    // handle your errors here
}
```

You can pass in the name with or without the extension and it will be found - note, this is NOT case insensitive ... so `XYZ` won't match `xyz.jpg` - easily changed if you need case insensitivity

Answer (score -1):

There are only a few known image extensions like jpg, png, gif, jpeg. Maybe try and fetch the file with best guess extension, if it throws exception try the next format.